# JS: debugging a Map-based trie tree

Tags: javascript, dictionary, tree, trie

I've implemented a Trie tree using a JS Map.
Each entry is a TrieBlock defined as follow:

```
class TrieBlock {
  constructor (key) {
    this.related = new Map() // children (key => UID) 
    this.key = key // node key in Trie
    this.eof = false // end-of-word stop flag
    this.data = null // additional embeded data, associated with a word
  }


}

// and the Trie
class Trie {
  constructor(debug) {
    this.debug = debug
    this.entries = new Map()
    this.entries.set(null, new TrieBlock()) // Trie ROOT block

  }

  insert(str, withData) {
    // ... ok for me !
  }

  has(word) {
    // walk through Trie
    // seek for the word
  }

  fetch(word) {
    // fetch the data associated with the word
  }
}
```

Why flattening the trie in a Map ? Just for easing the serialization process. OK, there's an over cost for storing UIDs : these are 8-hex-digits UIDs (like 'a2b4c6d8' is), but I'hope it can speed uo acccess, since Map is time-constant complexity.

My question is : how to pretty print all prefixes for debugging purposes ? I tried to use a DFS (Deep-First Search) algorithm but it's tricky

Something like:

```
trie.insert('CAR', 'Vroom!')  
trie.inseert('CAST', 'Habracadabra')
trie.inseert('CAR', 'Meow!')
```

Which may output:

```
* ROOT
    . C
      . A
        . R : Vroom!
        . S
          . T : Habracadra!
        . T : Meow!
```

EDIT:

By runinng that in console :

```
$ node dist/test-debug.js
```

when dist/test-debug.js is :

```
var ecmasy = require('ecmasy');

trie = new e cmasy.Trie();

trie.insert('DESCAT');
trie.insert('DESCAMP');
trie.insert('DESTOOP');

console.log('' + trie);
```

we obtain something like:

```
ecmasy/Trie:

 0 : null  false
 * 1 : D  false
 * * 2 : E  false
  * * * 3 : S  false
 * * * * 4 : C  false
 * * * * 4 : T  false
 * * * * * 5 : A  false
 * * * * * 5 : O  false
 * * * * * * 6 : T  true
 * * * * * * 6 : M  false
 * * * * * * 6 : O  false
 * * * * * * * 7 : P  true
 * * * * * * * 7 : P  true
```

Whith stack length, symbol and foef flag value are.

But the proper answer would be more likely:

```
D
+ D
  + S
    + C
      + A
        +M
          +P
        +T
         +O
           +O
             +P
```

EDIT: (2)

I will provide sooner a serialization algorithm that one wants to be run with a custom callback function for serializing user-defined data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to implement a Trie tree with a Map, since you could just use a Map in the first place.

Comment: for auto-completion purposes...

Comment: What have you tried?  Show some code and describe what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: please refer to this repo: github / hefeust / ecmasy project. I'v tried  to store 4,750+ bus stops names (total 52k of cumulated strings lengths) and it allocates 8,500+ blocks in the trie tree underlying map !

Comment: I meant your source code where you've tried to solve the problem and a description of the problem(s) with that attempt.  Also please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

With a coorect DFS :

```
 after inserting "DESTOOP", "DESCAT", "LYS" and "DESCAMP" strings :

 : null  false
  : D  false
   : E  false
    : S  false
     : C  false
      : A  false
       : M  false
        : P  true
       : T  true
     : T  false
     : O  false
       : O  false
        : P  true
  : L  false
   : Y  false
    : S  true
```

this DFS gives the correct output, liken an opened folders tree windows does, but in console. Commits in repo github > hefeust > ecmasy come sooner.

Enjoy your afternoon !